# PLS-00103 error for PLSQL block written to compare data in 2 indentical tables

Tags: plsql, syntax-error

Below is the block we have written to compare to identical tables but we are getting below error. Can someone please help in resolving this issue.

Code:

```
drop table ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE;

CREATE TABLE ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE
(
  CUSTOMER_NO         NUMBER(9),
  CREDIT_REASON_S      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S     CHAR(1 BYTE),
  L9_BILLING_TYPE_S     VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  PRODUCT_S           VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  CHARGE_CODE_S       VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  BILL_SEQ_NO_S       NUMBER(12),
  AMOUNT_S            NUMBER,
  TAX_AMOUNT_S        NUMBER,
  REV_AMOUNT_S        NUMBER,
  REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S    NUMBER,
  CREDIT_REASON_T      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T     CHAR(1 BYTE),
  L9_BILLING_TYPE_T     VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  PRODUCT_T           VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  CHARGE_CODE_T       VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  BILL_SEQ_NO_T       NUMBER(12),
  AMOUNT_T            NUMBER,
  TAX_AMOUNT_T        NUMBER,
  REV_AMOUNT_T        NUMBER,
  REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T    NUMBER,
  CREDIT_DATE_S         DATE,
  CREDIT_DATE_T         DATE,
  L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE  VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  AMOUNT_DIFF         NUMBER,
  TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF     NUMBER,
  REV_AMOUNT_DIFF     NUMBER,
  REV_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF NUMBER
);
COMMIT;

DECLARE 

v_CUSTOMER_NO_S         NUMBER(9),
v_CREDIT_REASON_S       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S     CHAR(1 BYTE),
v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_S     VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
v_PRODUCT_S             VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
v_CHARGE_CODE_S         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
v_BILL_SEQ_NO_S         NUMBER(12),
v_AMOUNT_S              NUMBER,
v_TAX_AMOUNT_S          NUMBER,
v_REV_AMOUNT_S          NUMBER,
v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S      NUMBER,
v_CREDIT_DATE_S         DATE,
v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S  VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
--v_CUSTOMER_NO_T         NUMBER(9),
--v_CREDIT_REASON_T       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T     CHAR(1 BYTE),
v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_T     VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
v_PRODUCT_T             VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
v_CHARGE_CODE_T         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
v_BILL_SEQ_NO_T         NUMBER(12),
v_AMOUNT_T              NUMBER,
v_TAX_AMOUNT_T          NUMBER,
v_REV_AMOUNT_T          NUMBER,
v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T      NUMBER,
--v_CREDIT_DATE_T         DATE,
--v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_T  VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
v_AMOUNT_DIFF           NUMBER,
v_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF       NUMBER,
v_REV_AMOUNT_DIFF       NUMBER,
v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF   NUMBER

  --commit_counter NUMBER(9);

CURSOR c_EXIST_IN_BOTH IS      
          (SELECT  CUSTOMER_NO , CREDIT_REASON , CREDIT_DATE , L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE
            FROM adjustment_detail_rpt
            INTERSECT
             SELECT  CUSTOMER_NO , CREDIT_REASON , CREDIT_DATE , L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE
               FROM adjustment_detail_rpt1);

BEGIN    
    --commit_counter := 0;    
        DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(1) );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Creating Compare Records...');        
        OPEN c_EXIST_IN_BOTH;
        LOOP
                FETCH c_EXIST_IN_BOTH INTO  v_CUSTOMER_NO_S , v_CREDIT_REASON_S , v_CREDIT_DATE_S , v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S;
                EXIT WHEN c_EXIST_IN_BOTH%NOTFOUND;
                BEGIN       
                    SELECT        
                        CREDIT_REASON
                        ,AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE
                        ,L9_BILLING_TYPE
                        ,PRODUCT
                        ,CHARGE_CODE
                        ,BILL_SEQ_NO
                        ,AMOUNT
                        ,TAX_AMOUNT
                        ,REV_AMOUNT
                        ,REV_TAX_AMOUNT
                        ,CREDIT_DATE
                        ,L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE        
                    INTO      
                        v_CREDIT_REASON_S
                        ,v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S
                        ,v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_S
                        ,v_PRODUCT_S
                        ,v_CHARGE_CODE_S
                        ,v_BILL_SEQ_NO_S
                        ,v_AMOUNT_S
                        ,v_TAX_AMOUNT_S
                        ,v_REV_AMOUNT_S
                        ,v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S
                        ,v_CREDIT_DATE_S
                        ,v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S
                    FROM adjustment_detail_rpt1
                    WHERE 
                        CUSTOMER_NO =  v_CUSTOMER_NO_S
                        AND L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE = v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S
                        AND CREDIT_REASON = v_L9_CREDIT_REASON_S
                        AND CREDIT_DATE = v_CREDIT_DATE_S
            END ;


            BEGIN            
                    SELECT 
                        CREDIT_REASON
                        ,AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE
                        ,L9_BILLING_TYPE
                        ,PRODUCT
                        ,CHARGE_CODE
                        ,BILL_SEQ_NO
                        ,AMOUNT
                        ,TAX_AMOUNT
                        ,REV_AMOUNT
                        ,REV_TAX_AMOUNT
                        ,CREDIT_DATE
                        ,L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE       
                    INTO       
                        v_CREDIT_REASON_T
                        ,v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T
                        ,v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_T
                        ,v_PRODUCT_T
                        ,v_CHARGE_CODE_T
                        ,v_BILL_SEQ_NO_T
                        ,v_AMOUNT_T
                        ,v_TAX_AMOUNT_T
                        ,v_REV_AMOUNT_T
                        ,v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T
                        ,v_CREDIT_DATE_T
                        ,v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S            
                    FROM 
                        adjustment_detail_rpt
                    WHERE 
                        CUSTOMER_NO =  v_CUSTOMER_NO_S
                        AND L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE = v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S
                        AND CREDIT_REASON = v_L9_CREDIT_REASON_S
                        AND CREDIT_DATE = v_CREDIT_DATE_S
            END ;

             INSERT INTO 
                ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE
             VALUES 
                (
                v_CUSTOMER_NO_S,
                v_CREDIT_REASON_S,
                v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S ,
                v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_S ,
                v_PRODUCT_S  ,
                v_CHARGE_CODE_S ,
                v_BILL_SEQ_NO_S ,
                v_AMOUNT_S  ,
                v_TAX_AMOUNT_S ,
                v_REV_AMOUNT_S ,
                v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S ,
                v_CREDIT_REASON_T ,
                v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T ,
                v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_T ,
                v_PRODUCT_T  ,
                v_CHARGE_CODE_T ,
                v_BILL_SEQ_NO_T ,
                v_AMOUNT_T ,
                v_TAX_AMOUNT_T ,
                v_REV_AMOUNT_T ,
                v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T ,
                v_CREDIT_DATE_S ,
                v_CREDIT_DATE_T ,
                v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S ,
                NULL ,
                NULL ,
                NULL ,
                NULL
                ); 
            COMMIT;
         END LOOP;                              
CLOSE c_EXIST_IN_BOTH;

        UPDATE 
            ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE
        SET        
            AMOUNT_DIFF  = NVL (AMOUNT_S , 0) - NVL(AMOUNT_T , 0) ,
            TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF  = NVL (TAX_AMOUNT_S , 0) - NVL(TAX_AMOUNT_T , 0) ,
            REV_AMOUNT_DIFF  = NVL (REV_AMOUNT_S , 0) - NVL(REV_AMOUNT_T , 0) ,
            REV_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF  = NVL (REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S , 0) - NVL(REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T , 0)
        COMMIT;     

END;            
/
```

Errors :

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

   := ; not null default character
ORA-06550: line 36, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CURSOR" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( , @ % ; not null range default external character
```

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow is not a debugging tool. But, you should put semicolon after each variable declaration. Also, check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for formatting code.

Answer (score 1):

Just some plain syntax errors. This is what it should be:

```
DROP TABLE ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE;

CREATE TABLE ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE
(
   CUSTOMER_NO           NUMBER (9),
   CREDIT_REASON_S       VARCHAR2 (10 BYTE),
   AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S     CHAR (1 BYTE),
   L9_BILLING_TYPE_S     VARCHAR2 (1 BYTE),
   PRODUCT_S             VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE),
   CHARGE_CODE_S         VARCHAR2 (25 BYTE),
   BILL_SEQ_NO_S         NUMBER (12),
   AMOUNT_S              NUMBER,
   TAX_AMOUNT_S          NUMBER,
   REV_AMOUNT_S          NUMBER,
   REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S      NUMBER,
   CREDIT_REASON_T       VARCHAR2 (10 BYTE),
   AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T     CHAR (1 BYTE),
   L9_BILLING_TYPE_T     VARCHAR2 (1 BYTE),
   PRODUCT_T             VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE),
   CHARGE_CODE_T         VARCHAR2 (25 BYTE),
   BILL_SEQ_NO_T         NUMBER (12),
   AMOUNT_T              NUMBER,
   TAX_AMOUNT_T          NUMBER,
   REV_AMOUNT_T          NUMBER,
   REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T      NUMBER,
   CREDIT_DATE_S         DATE,
   CREDIT_DATE_T         DATE,
   L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE    VARCHAR2 (4 BYTE),
   AMOUNT_DIFF           NUMBER,
   TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF       NUMBER,
   REV_AMOUNT_DIFF       NUMBER,
   REV_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF   NUMBER
);

COMMIT;

DECLARE
   v_CUSTOMER_NO_S          NUMBER (9);
   v_CREDIT_REASON_S        VARCHAR2 (10 BYTE);
   v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S      CHAR (1 BYTE);
   v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_S      VARCHAR2 (1 BYTE);
   v_PRODUCT_S              VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE);
   v_CHARGE_CODE_S          VARCHAR2 (25 BYTE);
   v_BILL_SEQ_NO_S          NUMBER (12);
   v_AMOUNT_S               NUMBER;
   v_TAX_AMOUNT_S           NUMBER;
   v_REV_AMOUNT_S           NUMBER;
   v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S       NUMBER;
   v_CREDIT_DATE_S          DATE;
   v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S   VARCHAR2 (4 BYTE);
   --v_CUSTOMER_NO_T         NUMBER(9),
   --v_CREDIT_REASON_T       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
   v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T      CHAR (1 BYTE);
   v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_T      VARCHAR2 (1 BYTE);
   v_PRODUCT_T              VARCHAR2 (16 BYTE);
   v_CHARGE_CODE_T          VARCHAR2 (25 BYTE);
   v_BILL_SEQ_NO_T          NUMBER (12);
   v_AMOUNT_T               NUMBER;
   v_TAX_AMOUNT_T           NUMBER;
   v_REV_AMOUNT_T           NUMBER;
   v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T       NUMBER;
   --v_CREDIT_DATE_T         DATE,
   --v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_T  VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
   v_AMOUNT_DIFF            NUMBER;
   v_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF        NUMBER;
   v_REV_AMOUNT_DIFF        NUMBER;
   v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF    NUMBER;

   --commit_counter NUMBER(9);

   CURSOR c_EXIST_IN_BOTH
   IS
      (SELECT   CUSTOMER_NO,
                CREDIT_REASON,
                CREDIT_DATE,
                L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE
         FROM   adjustment_detail_rpt
       INTERSECT
       SELECT   CUSTOMER_NO,
                CREDIT_REASON,
                CREDIT_DATE,
                L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE
         FROM   adjustment_detail_rpt1);
BEGIN
   --commit_counter := 0;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (1000000);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (CHR (1));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Creating Compare Records...');

   OPEN c_EXIST_IN_BOTH;

   LOOP
      FETCH c_EXIST_IN_BOTH
         INTO
                   v_CUSTOMER_NO_S, v_CREDIT_REASON_S, v_CREDIT_DATE_S, v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S;

      EXIT WHEN c_EXIST_IN_BOTH%NOTFOUND;

      BEGIN
         SELECT   CREDIT_REASON,
                  AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                  L9_BILLING_TYPE,
                  PRODUCT,
                  CHARGE_CODE,
                  BILL_SEQ_NO,
                  AMOUNT,
                  TAX_AMOUNT,
                  REV_AMOUNT,
                  REV_TAX_AMOUNT,
                  CREDIT_DATE,
                  L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE
           INTO   v_CREDIT_REASON_S,
                  v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S,
                  v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_S,
                  v_PRODUCT_S,
                  v_CHARGE_CODE_S,
                  v_BILL_SEQ_NO_S,
                  v_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_TAX_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_REV_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_CREDIT_DATE_S,
                  v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S
           FROM   adjustment_detail_rpt1
          WHERE       CUSTOMER_NO = v_CUSTOMER_NO_S
                  AND L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE = v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S
                  AND CREDIT_REASON = v_L9_CREDIT_REASON_S
                  AND CREDIT_DATE = v_CREDIT_DATE_S;
      END;


      BEGIN
         SELECT   CREDIT_REASON,
                  AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                  L9_BILLING_TYPE,
                  PRODUCT,
                  CHARGE_CODE,
                  BILL_SEQ_NO,
                  AMOUNT,
                  TAX_AMOUNT,
                  REV_AMOUNT,
                  REV_TAX_AMOUNT,
                  CREDIT_DATE,
                  L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE
           INTO   v_CREDIT_REASON_T,
                  v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T,
                  v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_T,
                  v_PRODUCT_T,
                  v_CHARGE_CODE_T,
                  v_BILL_SEQ_NO_T,
                  v_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_TAX_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_REV_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_CREDIT_DATE_T,
                  v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S
           FROM   adjustment_detail_rpt
          WHERE       CUSTOMER_NO = v_CUSTOMER_NO_S
                  AND L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE = v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S
                  AND CREDIT_REASON = v_L9_CREDIT_REASON_S
                  AND CREDIT_DATE = v_CREDIT_DATE_S;
      END;

      INSERT INTO ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE
        VALUES   (v_CUSTOMER_NO_S,
                  v_CREDIT_REASON_S,
                  v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_S,
                  v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_S,
                  v_PRODUCT_S,
                  v_CHARGE_CODE_S,
                  v_BILL_SEQ_NO_S,
                  v_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_TAX_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_REV_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S,
                  v_CREDIT_REASON_T,
                  v_AR_ACCOUNT_TYPE_T,
                  v_L9_BILLING_TYPE_T,
                  v_PRODUCT_T,
                  v_CHARGE_CODE_T,
                  v_BILL_SEQ_NO_T,
                  v_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_TAX_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_REV_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T,
                  v_CREDIT_DATE_S,
                  v_CREDIT_DATE_T,
                  v_L9_TELCO_COMP_CODE_S,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  NULL);

      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c_EXIST_IN_BOTH;

   UPDATE   ADJUSTMENT_DETAIL_RPT_COMPARE
      SET   AMOUNT_DIFF = NVL (AMOUNT_S, 0) - NVL (AMOUNT_T, 0),
            TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF = NVL (TAX_AMOUNT_S, 0) - NVL (TAX_AMOUNT_T, 0),
            REV_AMOUNT_DIFF = NVL (REV_AMOUNT_S, 0) - NVL (REV_AMOUNT_T, 0),
            REV_TAX_AMOUNT_DIFF =
               NVL (REV_TAX_AMOUNT_S, 0) - NVL (REV_TAX_AMOUNT_T, 0);

   COMMIT;
END;
/
```